# Loop through Multidemensional array with unknown amount PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a Multidimensional array, with an unknown amount of inner array. So it could be 4, 5, 6, 7 etc. I want to loop through the Multidimensional array and pick out each 6, 7 and 8 key. How can I do this?

**My Multidimensional Array**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [0] => Foo
        [1] => Bar
        [2] => 
        [3] =>
        [4] => 1234
        [5] => 5678
        [6] => 91011
        [7] => 20170718
        [8] => TBC
        [9] =>

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Foo
        [1] => Foo
        [2] => Bar
        [3] =>
        [4] => 1111
        [5] => 2222
        [6] => 3333
        [7] => 4444
        [8] => 5
        [9] =>

    )


 [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bar
        [1] => Foo
        [2] => Bar
        [3] =>
        [4] => 7777
        [5] => 9999999
        [6] => 33433
        [7] => 24
        [8] => 5
        [9] =>

    )
```

So in this example there is array[0], array[1] and array[2]. In another occasion there could be up to array[15]. The end array number is unknown. Regardless of how many arrays there are in the Multi dimension, I want to pick the 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th element of each array along with their values.

**What I currently Have**

```
    foreach( $fields as $key => $field) {

         echo $fields[ $key ];

         echo "\n";

    }
```

**OUTPUT OF ECHO**

```
  Array
  Array
  Array
  Array
  Array
  Array
  Array
  Array
  Array
```

How can this be put in a for loop so that all the 4,5,6,7 elements are assigned to a variable and echod out?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
<?php

$array = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
        0 => "FOO",
        1 => "BAR",
        2 => "",
        3 => "",
        4 => 1234,
        5 => 5678,
        6 => 91011,
        7 => 20170718,
        8 => "TBC",
        9 => ""
    ),
1 => Array
    (
        0 => "Foo",
        1 => "Foo",
        2 => "Bar",
        3 => "",
        4 => 1111,
        5 => 2222,
        6 => 3333,
        7 => 4444,
        8 => 5,
        9 => "",
    ),
 2 => Array
    (
        0 => "Bar",
        1 => "Foo",
        2 => "Bar",
        3 => "",
        4 => 7777,
        5 => 9999999,
        6 => 33433,
        7 => 24,
        8 => 5,
        9 => "",
    )
);

$all4567values = extract4567Elements($array);

var_dump($all4567values);
exit;
function extract4567Elements (array $array)
{
    $elements4567 = [];

    $index = 0;
    foreach ($array as $element){
        if(is_array($element)){
            $elements4567 = array_merge($elements4567, extract4567Elements($element));
        }else{
            if($index == 4 || $index == 5 || $index == 6 || $index == 7){
                $elements4567[] = $element;
            } 
        }
        $index++;
    }
    return $elements4567;
}
```

This outputs

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  int(1234)
  [1]=>
  int(5678)
  [2]=>
  int(91011)
  [3]=>
  int(20170718)
  [4]=>
  int(1111)
  [5]=>
  int(2222)
  [6]=>
  int(3333)
  [7]=>
  int(4444)
  [8]=>
  int(7777)
  [9]=>
  int(9999999)
  [10]=>
  int(33433)
  [11]=>
  int(24)
}
```

See a demo (https://eval.in/833525)

Please note that this function will extract the 4,5,6,7 values from the  nested arrays at deeper levels if there any.